# is there a way to return firebase snapshot in firebase cloudapi?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that lazy loades documents, inorder for it to fetch the later documents i will need to use the startafter method, and i need the last snapshot for it but firebase cloud api wont let me return the last visibale document snapshot, below is the function which returns the first two documents

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


const fetchInitialPosts = async (data, context) => {
  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const snapshot = await db
      .collection("feedPosts")
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .limit(2)
      .get();

  let lastVisible = null;
  if (!snapshot.empty) {
    lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  }
  // a function that parses the info into readable info(it works)
  const postsWithUserDetails = await Promise.all(
      snapshot.docs.map((postDoc) => fetchPostWithUserDetails(postDoc, uid)),
  );
  
  
  return {
    postsWithUserDetails,
    lastVisible,
  };
};
exports.fetchInitialPosts = functions.https.onCall(fetchInitialPosts);
```

note that if i send the result of "postsWithUserDetails" and put null in lastVisible the function runs perfectly so the problem only comes from trying to return the snapshot

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if your question contains everything we need in order to duplicate the behavior.  This includes: 1) all of the relevent contents of the database (we don't know what you're querying), 2) the actual results that you think are incorrect, 3) the results that you expect that are different.  We can't see any of that with what you have now in your question.

Comment: if you want to duplicate the behavior then open a cloud firebase api  then create a function and inside it replicate the  "snapshot" variable with a collection of your choice, then return snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1] and you will encounter the error: Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I suggest putting your specific instructions into the question itself so your question doesn't get closed for lacking information.   I'll point out that you still haven't said anything about the contents of your database, which is crucial for understanding what this code will do when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Callable Cloud Functions return values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#sending_back_the_result):

> To send data back to the client, return **data that can be JSON encoded**

So the return type should only contain data that can be [JSON encoded](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and the `DocumentSnapshot` object(s) you are trying to return don't meet that requirement (as they likely contains method definitions as well as data).

Given that, there is no way to return a `DocumentSnapshot` from a Cloud Function. The closest you can get is by returning the `id` and `data()` from the snapshot, and then using that in the client to accomplish your use-case.

Comment: Using the snapshot id in the startAfter method doesnt work

Comment: It *can* work if you pass the correct values. If you check the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter), there are two overload for `startAfter` - one that takes a `DocumentSnapshot` and one that takes a list of values. Since you can't pass a document snapshot from the Cloud Function, you will have to use the overload that takes a list of values. Also see the documentation on query pagination on multiple fields: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields

Comment: well i peginate with timestamps and for some reason the startAfter method is problematic with timestemps therfore you have to insert the doc itself. but luckiley i found a workaround, i take the id as an argument and just fetch the doc and insert it in the starAfter method. a bit nasty since it requires an additional call but it does the job so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. thnaks

Comment: I've seen that workaround more frequently recently. It's good that it works of course, but you are right: it *does* take an extra call - and it really shouldn't be needed as the API can take field values too (precisely for this type of situations where you can't persist/transfer a `DocumentSnapshot` object).

Comment: i searched for a way to use a timestamp in the startAfter method for months before giving up. i inserted the last document "createdAt" field which is a tumestamp in the StartAfter method (and in the orderBy i inserted ("createdAt","desc") )and for some reason it kept on giving me the first two docs. so i gave up on that. i would highly appriciate it if you could redirect me to a page with a working code example. thanks for giving me your time

Comment: That's the link I put in the second comment here. If that doesn't work for you, I recommend opening a new question with the code that you think should work for `startAfter` with field values, so I (and others) can have a look there.